# Postgresql - changing conf file parameters

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to change some parameteres in postgresql.conf file. I changed the parameters to following values

1. Shared_buffers: 8000MB
2. work_mem: 3200MB
3. maintenance_work_mem: 1600MB

I have postgresql installed on 128GB RAM server. After making these changes I restarted postgresql server. After that when I use psql to check these parameters using show (parameter_name) I get the following values.

1. Shared_buffers: 8000MB
2. work_mem: 4MB
3. maintenance_work_mem: 2047MB

Why did the changes reflect correctly only in the shared_buffer parameter but not in the other two?

I changed the max_wal_size to 4GB and min_wal_size to 1000MB but these parameters did not change too and the values shown are 1GB and 80MB. So in conclustion, of all the changes that I made only the changes to shared_buffers parameter got reflected while others did not change.

Comment: Which operating system are you using?

Comment: server is hosted on linux os

Comment: I restarted the server using "/etc/init.d/postgresql restart" after making the changes. I also opened the conf file to check if the changes were saved or not in that file.

Comment: If I change the parameters in the conf file of the server then I am assuming that these changes take place across all databases too since the changes were made on the server level.

Comment: There is an upper limit to `work_mem` if I'm not mistaken, try changing that manually for a session using `set work_mem = '3200MB'` - if the limit is exceeded you will get an error message.

Comment: I used the command you suggested using pgadmin4 and when I use the show command then it does show '3200MB' so the changes took place. Then I tried to login from pgadmin using another machine but with the same user then it shows the value as '4MB' so it means that the command that you suggested is only for session level. How do I change it permamently then? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some possibilities what might be the problem:

- You edited the wrong `postgresql.conf`.
- You restarted the wrong server.
- The value was configured with `ALTER SYSTEM`.
- The value was configured with `ALTER USER` or `ALTER DATABASE`.
  Use the psql command `\drds` to see such settings.

To figure out from where PostgreSQL takes the setting, use

```
SELECT * FROM pg_settings WHERE name = 'work_mem';
```

Comment: I made the query that you suggested and what I found was sourcefile & sourceline field were null/empty for work_mem while for shared_buffers sourcefile is /etc/postgresql/9.5/main/postgresql.conf. This is the exact file that I edited. I am sure that restarted the correct server.

The parameters are being taken from following files
'shared_buffers' - postgresql.conf
'work_mem' - null/empty
'maintenance_work_mem' - postgresql.auto.conf
min_wal_size/max_wal_size - null/empty


Why do I have null in some of the sourcefile field? How do I make postgres take params from correct file.

Comment: I solved the issue. It was a very silly error. Some of the parameter lines were commented out (#) but shared_buffer wasn't so that change was being reflected while other changes were not.